# How to merge sample points that are within a certain distance of each other and calculate mean attributes values for merged points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, merge, combine, average

I have a data set like the following in `.csv`:

| sample | latitude | longitude | variable1 | variable2 | variable3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 37.18 | -115.85 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 37.18 | -115.85 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 37.18 | -115.85 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| D | 39.44 | -117.66 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| E | 39.36 | -117.72 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 0 |
| F | 39.6 | -117.94 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| G | 38.12 | -111.5 | 0 | 0.1 | 0.9 |
| H | 37.95 | -114.36 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I read this data into QGIS and make pie charts using the three numeric variables (which are proportions bounded between 0 and 1 for each sample) to obtain a map like the following:

[image]

My real data set contains thousands of samples, so there's a lot of overlapping points and I'd like to merge points that are, say, less than 15 km from each other. Pie charts of merged points must be of averaged values for the numeric variables. Note that values are bounded between 0 and 1, and they must remain that way when averaged. To show that there are samples that have been merged, I'd also like the size of the pie charts to be proportional to the number of samples that they represent. How could I do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but the GRASS GIS module [`v.neighbors`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.neighbors.html) might help. This module creates a **raster**, with cell size that you specify (15km in your case) where the value of each raster cell is some function of the attribute values of points contained in each cell. So you would choose `method="average"`.  You could then revert back to points, with `r.to.vect ... type=point` and follow up with removing all points with value=0.

HTH